# Excel Insert Function Tool Displaying Different Result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that according to the insert function tool calculates the correct answer, but the cell does NOT display the correct answer.[image][image] See attached images.

Formula is as follows:

```
=ROUND(SUM(SUMIFS(TRANSACTIONS!$D$11:$D$9999,TRANSACTIONS!$E$11:$E$9999,ACCOUNTS!$A12,TRANSACTIONS!$B$11:$B$9999, ">="&ACCOUNTS!F$10,TRANSACTIONS!$B$11:$B$9999,"<"&ACCOUNTS!G$10),-SUMIFS(TRANSACTIONS!$D$11:$D$9999,TRANSACTIONS!$F$11:$F$9999,ACCOUNTS!$A12,TRANSACTIONS!$B$11:$B$9999, ">="&ACCOUNTS!F$10,TRANSACTIONS!$B$11:$B$9999,"<"&ACCOUNTS!G$10)),2)
```

"TRANSACTIONS" refers to a different sheet with a range. Let me know if further info is needed.

Comment: Might this formula need to be entered as being a 3D-version; i.e. hold CTRL while you hit ENTER. (The formula will then have { and } surrounding it as you place the cursor on the cell)

Comment: @Hannu this formula should function fine without the array entry. It's really a simple sumifs. As shown in the picture, in the fomula helper it displays the correct answer. But not in the cell.